# How can I get a reading time estimate?

Tags: word-processing

Is there any way to display the reading time estimate in Vim? For example "this will take about 4 minutes to read".

The closest that I know of is `g<C-g>`, which gives:

```
Col 29 of 75; Line 68 of 132; Word 285 of 520; Byte 2187 of 3977
```

But no reading time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in method for this, but I extended `g<C-g>` using the following function:

```
fun! s:readtime()
    let l:status = v:statusmsg
    try
        exe "silent normal! g\<C-g>"
        echo printf('%s; About %.0f minutes',
                    \ v:statusmsg, ceil(wordcount()['words'] / 200.0))
    finally
        let v:statusmsg = l:status
    endtry
endfun
nnoremap g<C-g> :call <SID>readtime()<CR>
```

I opted to extend the `<C-g>g` output with an estimate of the reading time:

```
Col 1 of 17; Line 62 of 131; Word 261 of 510; Byte 1967 of 3920; About 3 minutes
```

This assumes a reading speed of 200 words per minute.

The trick is that you can read *and write* [`v:statusmsg`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Astatusmsg) to display a message in the commandline, so this first runs the default `g<C-g>`, captures the output, get the word count, adds the reading time, and sets the statusmsg again.

You can do the same but not set `v:statusmsg` at the end if you want it mapped to a separate key, or run it as a command.

Note that this will only give you a naïve estimate which us unaware of syntax. It should be accurate enough for simple markup languages like Markdown, but it won't work well for more verbose markup such as HTML.